# obtener el directorio global de mi script php

Tags: php, url

Buenas noches quisiera ver si existe alguna funcion que me permita obtener el directorio principal de mis url; por ejemplo tengo la siguiente url:

```
https://miwebsite.com/***estoquiero***/hola.php?dasdas=asdasd
```

ó

```
https://miwebsite.com/***estoquiero***/otrodir/otrodir/hola.php?dasdas=asdasd
```

como veran lo unico que deseo filtrar es el sub directorio (estoquiero) que le sigue al dominio

intente con esto:

```
$url = 'https://miwebsite.com/***estoquiero***/otrodir/otrodir/hola.php?dasdas=asdasd';
echo "<textarea>";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
echo "<textarea>";
```

y obtengo una url parseada, queria saber si existe alguna forma de obtenerlo directamente

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por *directorio global*? Además, ¿qué quieres hacer con eso exactamente? Lo habitual para estos casos es definir constantes de tus rutas y usar dichas constantes.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que deseo es por ejemplo mi url https://mipagina.com/ID_CLIENTE/hola.php?gsdfsd=123
en donde ID_CLIENTE es el id de mi cliente y esto varia segun cada cliente, lo que yo deseo es obtener ese fragmento (ese id)